# How to issue roles using slash commands? DiscordJS

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to make the issuance of roles through a slash command. So that you can choose which role to give to the participant. Information from the Internet did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('giverole')
    .setDescription('Gives a role to a user.')
    .addUserOption(option => option.setName('user').setDescription('The user to give the role to').setRequired(true))
    .addRoleOption(option => option.setName('role').setDescription('The role to give to the user').setRequired(true)),
  async execute(interaction) {
    // Check if user has permission to manage roles
    if (!interaction.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_ROLES')) {
      return interaction.reply('You do not have permission to manage roles.');
    }

    // Get the mentioned user and role
    const member = interaction.options.getMember('user');
    const role = interaction.options.getRole('role');

    // Give the mentioned role to the mentioned user
    member.roles.add(role)
      .then(() => {
        interaction.reply(`Successfully gave ${role.name} role to ${member.user.tag}`);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        interaction.reply('There was an error while giving the role.');
      });
  },
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.